# Manhwa where the main character is bullied in high school, gains powers with others, and is pursued by a scythe guy

Tags: story-identification, manga, powers

In the mahwa, the main character is a bullied high school boy and one day he gets powers like his in-game character. The systems call him and meets this rich orange-haired female classmate and there are others like them. They get chased by this scythe guy in the first few chapters.

Comment: So, does the setting stay on Earth, near the high school? No transportation to another world? Do any dungeons form? And by "system", do you mean something with an in-game interface? Or just that he gains powers?

Comment: Also, do you remember if this was black-and-white or color, what color the protagonist's hair is, and which site you might have read this on?

Comment: the setting is on earth, its not really a dungeon, its more like the monsters spawn  also the the female mc is a rich orange hair girl who is also his classmate. there is whole society of people just like him but each with their own powers . the fm power is like a physic i think

Comment: Monsters showing up is a good thing to [edit] into your question. So, I assume these are creatures from the game he was playing? Is everyone experiencing the same monsters, or do some of them face them from some other source? Is it implied that the game was another reality or that the monsters patterned themselves off of popular culture? What does the guy with the scythe look like? Traditional grim reaper? School uniform? Totally nude except for the weapon? Human? Undead? Monstrous?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Ultra-Alternate Character](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ultra-alternate-character)*. It is available on [Webtoons](https://www.webtoons.com/en/action/ultra-alternate-character/list?title_no=3581).

> In Ergosphere Online, a VR MMORPG craze, Oreum Lee is harshly mocked by his party members for being a mediocre healer. Not only that, **his teammates in the game bully him in real life at school**. Oreum’s saving grace is his alternate character, a powerful Avenger class character that he plays with extraordinary skill. **One day when Oreum logs out of the game, a glitch in the system imbues him with his alternate character’s abilities and forces him to fight against evil monsters from the in-game realm**. Will Oreum survive the game world and his school life at the same time?

The synopsis covers much of the details: the protagonist is a high school student that plays a game and is bullied by others. He awakens to a system and the game crosses over into the real world.

I believe this is the orange haired classmate.

[image: Rich classmate]

The person with the scythe shows up in chapter 8, after he fights a armored knight.

[image: Scythe dude]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Bullying` and `Monster/s`

Comment: yes omg thank you i been looking for it

Comment: @luckyeye You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).